# Number of Connections in Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, server

Simply I have a java server program and I want to count number of clients connected the socket, increment on new connection and decrement when connections are closed. 
What is the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: By maintaining a counter? Be careful about multithreading though

Comment: **I want to count number of clients connected the socket, increment on new connection and decrement when connections are closed. What is the best way to achieve this ?** , best way to achieve this is to actually **code** , only then can you figure out the best and the worst ways

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the code logic so you'd have to see the decrement part. And even this is a workaround I believe.

```
int count = 0;
serverSocket.accept(); 
count++;
```

And decrement it every time you close the socket.

Comment: You can post your function code so I can help you out better.